# Maximum distance between two nodes in a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I am trying to find the maximum distance between two nodes in a tree. Here is my program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class distance {

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> visited=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> depth=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> depth1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int sum=-1;
    static boolean[] arr;
    static int root=0;


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in.nextInt();     //no of nodes

        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)   
        {
            list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        int a;
        int b;
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)  //populating the adjacency list
        {
            a=in.nextInt();
            b=in.nextInt();
            list.get(a).add(b);
            list.get(b).add(a);
        }

        arr=new boolean[n+1];

        dfs(root);

        int final_sum=0;
        Collections.sort(depth1);
        System.out.println(depth1.get(depth1.size()-1)+depth1.get(depth1.size()-2));

        }
    public static void dfs(int n)
    {   
        arr[n]=true;
        visited.add(n);
        sum=sum+1;

        if(list.get(n).size()==1)
        {   
            depth.add(sum); //add the depth to the arraylist when we reach a leaf node.Note the this will not run if the root node has only one child but I've ignored the case.
        }
        if(n==root)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<list.get(0).size();j++)
            {   
                dfs(list.get(0).get(j)); //recursion on each child of the root node
                sum=0;
                Collections.sort(depth);
                depth1.add(depth.get(depth.size()-1));
                depth.clear();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            for(int l:list.get(n))
            if(!arr[l]==true)
            {
                dfs(l);
                sum--;

            }
        }


    }

}
```

The program seems to be running; but isn't showing the correct output for some of the test cases. The approach I've taken is:

1. Find the number of children of the root node (I've always taken the root node to be 0).
2. Find the maximum depth of each sub-tree (As many sub-trees as there are children of the root node).
3. Store the maximum depth of each sub-tree in an `ArrayList`, sort it and print the sum of the last two values.

Can someone please point out the error in my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the algorithm in the first place.
You assume that the maximum distance between two nodes always contains root node, while this does not always hold true.

Here is an example:

[image: Tree example]

The nodes from the longest path are marked with red color.
The longest path has length of `6` and contains `7` nodes, while your algorithm only finds paths that go through the root and therefore prints `5` as its answer.

Comment: Thanks. Really silly of me to make such a naive mistake.

Comment: @PrashantPandey, please kindly accept the answer if that is what you were looking for